# How I can classify host as down when one service (one Windows process) is down in Nagios?

Tags: nagios, process

I would like to classify host as down when one Windows service is in critical state (for example not working Windows process). Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: Is it a specified process or do you have multiple processes and you want to mark host as down when one of them is stopped?

Comment: For now I want to monitor one process per server (for example when mail server process is not present in process list I want to mark this host as down even when Windows itself is working correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by replacing the check_command for the host (normally it's an ICMP ping) with one that checks for something else.